# Как мне отправить данные с Android телефона, мне на компьютер черз интернет каждые секунд 10-20

Tags: java, android, wifi

У меня етсь приложениена телефоне, которое генерирует рандомные  чила, и мне эти рандомные числа нужно передать на мой компьютер, Вы скажите передай по локальной сети, но телефон будет далеко от меня

Comment: если не по сети, то есть ещё много вариантов: звук, свет, вибрации, гравитационные возмущения, радиация, ментальные волны и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: мне нужно по Wifi по интернету

Comment: можно сделать типа чата, или через firebase что-то сочинить

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Не смешно, а новичку автору в этой теме вопроса обидно. Какой смысл в этом комментарии?

Answer (score 1):

можешь попробовать отправить по почте. Если это папка с файлами, то сожми ее и отправь

Comment: Каждые 10 секунд?